# How to mock in pytest global variable in imported module?

Tags: python, mocking, pytest

I have a module with methods, that I want to test with pytest. In my module I set up global vars such as logger. to use them in various places.

lib/sample.py

```
from common.logger import Logger

logger = Logger()

class Sample:
    def __init__(self):
        ...
```

common/logger.py

```
from google.cloud import logging

class Logger:
    def __init__(self):
        self.client = logging.Client()
        ...
```

tests/sample_test.py

```
from lib.sample import Sample

@mock.patch.object(Sample, "bar", return_value=None)
def test_foo():
    ...
```

I got this error when I run pytest:

```
../lib/sample_test.py:X: in <module>
    from lib.sample import Sample
../lib/sample.py:X: in <module>
    logger = Logger()
../common/logger.py:X: in __init__
    self.client = logging.Client()
../../../../XXX/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/logging_v2/client.py:122: in __init__
    client_options=client_options,
../../../../XXX/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/client.py:277: in __init__
    _ClientProjectMixin.__init__(self, project=project, credentials=credentials)
../../../../XXX/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/client.py:225: in __init__
    project = self._determine_default(project)
../../../../XXX/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/client.py:244: in _determine_default
    return _determine_default_project(project)
../../../../XXX/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/_helpers.py:186: in _determine_default_project
    _, project = google.auth.default()
../../../../XXX/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/auth/_default.py:356: in default
    raise exceptions.DefaultCredentialsError(_HELP_MESSAGE)
E   google.auth.exceptions.DefaultCredentialsError: Could not automatically determine credentials. Please set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS or explicitly create credentials and re-run the application. For more information, please see https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started
```

I should not solve this error to set the variable as a prerequisite to use this code for members.

How can I mock or patch any module or function?

Comment: I think that before that import, you can `import common.logger` and do `common.logger.Logger = some_working_mock_here`. - For sure it would work if you have `import common.logger` there because modules are always imported once, but I don't know about `from ... import ...`

Comment: If it doesn't work, then you should probably re-write your code to allow dependency injection. But I'm quite new at real automated testing as well.